# Can't update existing asset in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

I have an asset and I want to update degreeStatus property:

```
asset Degree identified by degreeId {
    o String degreeId
    o String graduateRut
    o String owner
    o String degreeType
    o String degreeStatus
    o String major
    o String minor
    o String gpa
    o String startYear
    o String gradYear
    o String university
    o String[] authorized optional
}
```

I have this function in the Node SDK:

```
updateDegreeData: async function (degreeId, updateData, uid) {

  let cardIdUni = await getUniversityCardId2(uid);
  console.log(cardIdUni);

  businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
  await businessNetworkConnection.connect(cardIdUni);

  degreesRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry(namespace + '.Degree');
  let degree = degreesRegistry.get(degreeId);
  degree.degreeStatus = updateData;

  degreesRegistry.update(degree);

  return degree

}
```

It's returning the asset I want to update but its not updating. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `degreesRegistry.update(degree);` is a Promise, you need to `await` it.

You might want to also either `try{} catch{}` or `.catch()` and see if anything is wrong with the `.update()`

Comment: Oh it was so simply. My mistake, I'm out of focus. Thanks for your help. In 5 minutes all mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again.